# Exit code of previous command execution is always 0 -- In Remote Shell Execution $?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to execute a script, In the midway of the script, it executes a part of the code in a remote shell and then again comes back to the same local shell.

However, my question is about the exit codes of the command executed in the remote shell. I am trying to do decision in remote with if-then-else based on the exit codes. When it didn't execute as expected I tried to narrow down the problem.

Here are my findings,

The output is always IP Found, as $? is always equal to 0.

```
ssh root@<remote server> bash -c "'
host www.google.com123
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "Invalid Host"
else
    echo "IP Found"
fi

'"
```

Also, in this case, the same output is expected

```
ssh root@<remote server> bash -c "'
host www.google.com
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "Invalid Host"
else
    echo "IP Found"
fi

'"
```

Ref: I got to know about this remote execution method from [here](https://zaiste.net/a_few_ways_to_execute_commands_remotely_using_ssh/)

Please Help me understand this behavior of remote shell execution. Also, if there are any other ways to execute a part of a shell-script in remote through ssh please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outermost quotes are double quotes, so `$?` is expanded locally before you ever run `bash` remotely. Instead, use

```
ssh root@<remote server> 'bash -c "
host www.google.com123
if [ \$? != 0 ]
then
    echo \"Invalid Host\"
else
    echo \"IP Found\"
fi

"'
```

Simpler is to avoid checking `$?` explicitly at all:

```
ssh root@<remote server> 'bash -c "
if ! host www.google.com123
then
    echo \"Invalid Host\"
else
    echo \"IP Found\"
fi

"'
```

Even simpler is not run a second unnecessary shell.

```
ssh root@<remote server> '
if ! host www.google.com123
then
    echo "Invalid Host"
else
    echo "IP Found"
fi
'
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to address this issue. I would go with explicit mention of the bash shell.  Just in case some other shell than bash is set to default.

Comment: Try to avoid non-standard constructions where possible, and because there are no `bash` extensions in your desired command, there's no reason to require anything more specific than a POSIX-compliant shell.